# Invoke the shell files in Android shell through Python

Tags: android, python, shell

My goal is to automate a scenario where I need to make calls and SMS from to a predefined mobile number periodically.

1. As of now I have created a python script that invokes the Dialer activity.
2. I have Decoded the key presses of all the numbers as a shell file and have pushed it in android shell under `/mnt/sdcard` (Every number has a separate shell file).

Can you please suggest to me how to invoke the shell files that are in Android shell through Python.

Comment: `/mnt/sdcard` directory usually does not have executable permissions.
Try using `/data/local/tmp` directory instead.

Comment: It's not clear what's in your shell scripts, provide examples.